# Use Mule message properties in MMC alert

Tags: notifications, mule

Is it possible to use mule message properties (like payload and flowvars) in a Mule Management Console notification body or subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible.
You can only use the properties exposed by mule, as explained here:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Defining+SLAs+and+Alerts#DefiningSLAsandAlerts-PropertiesUsedinAlertExpressions

Maybe using a Management Script, but there is no much info about it (the links to the javadoc are broken)

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Scripting+Examples#ScriptingExamples-AlertingExamples

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it. Mule provide various properties common to all alerts from class com.mulesoft.console.alert.RaisedAlert that can be used in defining the certain values such as 
Flow identifier
Flow name
You may refer to mule documentation for it
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-management-console/v/3.7/defining-slas-and-alerts#DefiningSLAsandAlerts-PropertiesUsedinAlertExpressions